# Как вернуть только количество найденных строк в базе в отношениях eloquent Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Всем привет!

Я "реализую" проект на Laravel с меню, где должны отображаться категории, у которых есть товары. Нет товаров - категория не отображается, всё просто.

У меня многоуровневое меню - есть родительская категория, у нее дочерняя, у нее еще одна дочерняя и т.д. (Одежда, обувь и аксессуары -> Одежда -> Футболки и поло -> Футболки)

Чтобы получить весь этот массив категорий я делаю следующее:

```
$allChildCategories = Category::where('name', $categoryName->name)->with('allChildrenCategories', 'products')->get()->toArray();
```

В самой модели Category вот такая связка:

```
    public function childrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function allChildrenCategories()
    {
        return $this->childrenCategories()->with('allChildrenCategories', 'products');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_title', 'title')->where('stock', 'in-stock');
    }
```

То есть фактически я беру категорию, которая мне нужна, получаю у нее все дочерние (кладу в массив  all_children_categories) и по этой категории нахожу все товары, принадлежащие ей и которые в наличии (кладу в массив products).

Отношения eloquent работают так, как надо. Ну... почти как надо.
Я думаю, что это не правильно, т.к. мне не нужны все данные о товарах, а только лишь есть они или нет. При этом я делаю такой большой запрос, который явно создаст большую нагрузку на базу данных. А когда товаров будет миллион - думаю, что всё вообще перестанет работать)))

Вопрос:

1. Как получить не все данные о товаре, а лишь узнать их количество? А лучше даже не количество, а просто есть они или нет.
   Пробую так, но все ломается:

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_title', 'title')->where('stock', 'in-stock')->count();
    }
```

2. Ну и этот вопрос можно оформить как отдельный, но вдруг найдутся знающие люди и подскажут =)
   Товары лежат, как правило, в последней дочерней категории. Но при этом, по моему замыслу, когда я вызываю меню (где должны отображаться только непустые категории), родительские категории тоже должны отображаться, но они не отобразятся, если если они пустые. Таким образом, как я написал код - они будут пустые, т.к. при запросе к таблице продуктов, например в категории "одежда" нет товаров, а в ее дочерней категории "футболки" они есть. Можно ли как-то решить эту задачу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы добавил еще одно поле в таблицу категорий, который обозначал бы что категория конечная и может иметь товары (например bool is_last)

Теперь можно получить все категории у которых могут быть товары но их точно нет.

```
$categoriesWithoutProducts = Category::where('is_last', true)
    ->whereDoesntHave('products')->get();
```

Дальше получаем категории без загрузки товаров и сразу исключаем пустые категории.

```
$сategories = Category::with('allChildrenCategories')
    ->whereNotIn('id', $categoriesWithoutProducts->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```